# cbind with empty objects for looping iteration

Tags: r, cbind

I would like to do a cbind with two data.frame objects. However the first one is empty, just created for loop iteration. I would like to know if it is possible.

When I try:

`data <- data.frame()`

`data1 <- cbind(data, mpg)`

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 234

I am not successful.

My loop is a little longer, but in general, I have about 100 files in which I need to create the `taxa_col_name` variable and I need to add the data.frame generated in the loop to a data.frame that will be my final base.

```
data <- data.frame()
    
for (i in 1:100) {
rate_col_name <- sprintf("rate_%s", i)
data1 <- data1 %>%
mutate(!!rate_col_name:=
       (population_2000)*((population_2010/population_2000_previous)))
       data1$population_2010 = NULL
       data1$population_2000_previous <- NULL
       rm(pop_2000_previous, pop_2010)
       gc()
date <- cbind(date, date1)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create an empty dataset?  You can just create a list of datasets and then use `do.call(cbind, lst1)`

Comment: It could be an alternative. I will try to generate my list objects in the loop. @akrun

Comment: Can you show your loop code.  It may help in understanding the code

Comment: I put the final part of the loop. @akrun

Comment: In your code, the columns `population_2000` and `population_2000_previous` seems to be the same from the original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you attempt to `cbind` the existing but empty `data` with `data1`, which actually has rows and presumably one column. That's because for cbind, the two data frames need to have the same nunmber of rows. A minimum example to produce that error is:

```
> data <- data.frame()
> data_input <- data.frame(mydata=1:10)
> cbind(data, data1)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 10
```

For you, this is happening at the end of the first iteration of your loop. Here's a shorter version of that:

```
> data_input <- rnorm(n = 10)
> data <- data.frame()
> for (i in 1:10) {
+   message("I'm in iteration ", i)
+   data1 <- data_input + i 
+   data <- cbind(data, data1)
+ }
I'm in iteration 1
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 10
```

One solution is to initialize `data` with actual data in the first iteration of the loop:

```
data_input <- seq(from=100, to=1000, by=100)
for (i in 1:10) {
  data1 <- data_input + i
  if(i==1){
    data <- data.frame(data1)
  }else{
    data <- cbind(data, data1)
  }
}
```

One could also do the first iteration "manually" outside the loop and then start the loop at 2 instead of 1:

```
data_input <- seq(from=100, to=1000, by=100)
data1 <- data_input + 1
data <- data.frame(data1)
for (i in 2:10) {
  data1 <- data_input + i
  data <- cbind(data, data1)
}
```

Another solution is to start with a `list` and turn that into a `data.frame` in the end:

```
data_input <- seq(from=100, to=1000, by=100)
data <- list()
for (i in 1:10){
  data1 <- data_input + i
  data[[i]] <- data1
}
data <- data.frame(do.call('cbind', data))
```